# Direct gap of a semimetal

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

In a semimetal, the direct gap is not zero, but the material is metallic. My question is, can the direct gap be measured with infrared absorption in a semimetal? Would we see full absorption due to the material being metallic, or would we be able to pick up the direct band gap?

Comment: The direct gap in a semi-metal is zero, otherwise it would be an insulator. I think you may be confusing concepts.

Comment: Indeed, just like for indirect semiconductors, you can measure it.

Comment: @KFGauss - no, the direct gap is non-zero. The filled portion of the conduction band is not at $k=0$, and where the conduction band minimum occurs there is still a gap to the valence band.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you very much, that makes sense to me. Is there a quick reference that you can point me to where the direct gap of a classic semimetal is measured in this way? I've been searching but Google keeps bringing up fancy kinds of semimetals (Weyl semimetals, nanoparticles etc.).